# Mongodb connection refused from other application in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, bitnami

I have below `mongodb` configuration in `docker-compose.yml` file -

```
version: '3.7'
networks:
 app-tier:
  driver: bridge

mongodb:
image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'
container_name: "mongodb"
environment:
  MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST: mongodb
  MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME: mongodb
  MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE: primary
  MONGODB_INITDB_DATABASE: testdb
  MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME: rs0
  ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  - ./scripts/mongorestore.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongorestore.sh
  - ./data/mongodb:/data/mongodb
networks:
  - app-tier


infrastructure:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  target: base
container_name: infra
environment:
  - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
  - KAFKA_BROKERS=kafka:9092
  - REDIS_ENDPOINT=redis
  - APP_NAME=infrastructure
volumes:
  - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
depends_on:
  - "kafka"
  - "redis"
  - "mongodb"   
networks:
  - app-tier
```

Whenever I run `docker-compose` my app infrastructure giving below error -

```
error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

Inside application I am not even trying to connect `mongodb`, I am just trying to set up my application first using `docker-compose`

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Something in `infrastructure` image is trying to connect to mongodb. **localhost is likely a default host**, if you didn't set it explicitly. You need to find out who is that and set host name to `mongodb`

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response, but I search in all files and also did global search for `localhost:27017` in `infrastructure` application, there is no file internally using it. Actually `infrastructure` is almost empty project

Comment: @ppb, I highlighted the important part. "by default" means it is not written. Same applies to the port number actually.